# AngularJS: Enable Button after Multiple Checkboxes as been "checked"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, checkbox

Lets say i have two Questions, each with their respective checkboxes and a "Next->" button. I want to enable the "Next" button, once  each Question has at least one checked checkbox. I have everything wrapped around a Form. Something like this

```
<form name="form_" novalidate>
 <div="cont_1" >
     <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data1.enabled" ng-required="!data1.enabled">
     </label>
      .
      . 
  </div>
  <div="cont_2" >
     <label>
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data5.enabled" ng-required="!data5.enabled">
     </label>
       .
       .
  </div>
  <button ng-disabled="form_.$invalid">
  </form>
```

The problem is that I have to select ALL checkboxes for the button to enable, i dont want that, what i want is for at least one from each question to be checked for the button to enable, it can be 1 & 1, 2 & 3 etc.. but not forcefully ALL of them. Ive used the ng-required with radiobutton before and it does work. Not the same with check boxes though. It seems the $invalid is checking for all of them to comply but that is not what i want.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using ng-required for checkboxes, because `required` for checkbox means that it has to be selected to be valid. So if you have some checkbox in the form that is `required` then is has to be checked to have the form being valid.

It works differently for radio buttons. `required` on radio buttons enforces selection of atleast one value.

Check this

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_required

You should maintain for each question something like a flag which could be set on selecting an answer for that question, and enable the button if these flags for all the questions are set.
`ng-required` is not the way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Nils - you are hoping to get something out of `ng-required` that it was not meant to do.

You need to either:

1. implement logic in some QuestionService that determines how many
   checked answers constitutes an answered question, and drive your
   view off of that logic, or
2. create a directive that monitors the checkboxes among its children.

For approach (1) I created a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pON3PmS77oqqe0aj4Fsb